# Firebase Analytics userID

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have an app and would like to do a lot of analyses on the user behaviour. As I understand it, I can link Firebase to BigQuery and export raw data.

What I'm interested in is whether Firebase will provide separate data for each user using the app or just an overall analysis?

In what way can I identify these users? Can I assign each user with a random userID for the purpose of being able to uniquely identify him? Users will have to login into the app but I don't (and can't) use their username as userID.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

If you connect Firebase Analytics to BigQuery, you get access to the raw event stream from Firebase in BigQuery. This includes all information that was sent from the client.

You can indeed [set the user ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setUserId(java.lang.String)) in your code, which will then be available in BigQuery. I'd recommend either using their existing [Firebase Authentication UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), or [signing them in with an anonymous account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) and using the UID.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this is more from a developer perspective. What I'm mainly interested in are the analytical functions.

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to using BigQuery jointly with Firebase and Google Analytics for cross-platform comparison - so that I'm able to uniquely identify each user and join data from both Firebase and GA360.

In other words, the login details for each user are already defined and stored at local servers and Firebase is only used for analyzing behavior in the app. But because of privacy reasons I'm not able to "upload" usernames to Firebase.